# How to install Maven on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, automation

I'm trying to install maven on eclipse marketplace but I'm Not able to install maven on eclipse it shows unable to read repository. Please help to install maven on eclipse and also tried that new software installation option in eclipse it also shows same like unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
And I tried different links also

Comment: A lot of Eclipse downloads include Maven as part of the install - look for "M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse" in the Installation Details. Otherwise it should be in the main Eclipse install repository (`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03` for the current Eclipse)

Comment: To be clear here you are not installing Maven. You are installing a plugin in Eclipse which support building/importing a project into Eclipse.